# How to add all files to gitignore without ignoring the folders?

Tags: git

This is my project structure:

```
|-- __main__.py
|-- __pycache__
`-- audios
    |-- keywords
    |   |-- foo1.wav
    |   `-- foo2.wav
    `-- target_audio
        |-- bar1.wav
        `-- bar2.wav
```

I have added `*.wav` to my `.gitignore`:

```
.idea
__pycache__/
*.wav
```

This is resulting in the whole directory tree under `audios/` getting ignored. I am assuming that since all the files in the directories are being ignored, the directory as a whole is being ignored by git. But I want to keep the directory structure along with the repository. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By how git is designed, it doesn't allow empty folders. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/115983/how-can-i-add-an-empty-directory-to-a-git-repository) stackoverflow post.

The post is suggesting to add a '.gitignore' to each of the empty folders so that they get tracked by git.

In my case,

```
touch audios/target_audio/.gitignore
touch audios/keywords/.gitignore
```

did the job.

Comment: Readmes, manifests, or anything similar work as a placeholder too.

Comment: My personal preference is to create `target_audio/.gitigignore` holding the pattern `*.wav` or just `*`, and commit that gitignore in that directory. You do end up with some duplicate `.gitignore` files, but so what?